# Turning Actor Messages into Observables

Tags: stream, akka, observable

I'm reading through this blog post:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-rxjava-observable

I have a couple of questions on that:

What is the benefit of using this approach that turns each of my Actor messages into an Observable? I can't visualize the benefit? Could anyone please help me explain with a scenario? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So I think the author was basically trying to make an actor a producer of events (publisher) in an Observable chain.  Akka has recently been doing just that with their Akka Streams project which is part of the Reactive Streams initiative which RXJava is also part of.  In the future, you will be able to use two technologies together seamlessly because both will implement the core Reactive Streams specification.

Comment: Actor messages are processed sequentially, one by one in its receive method. How would this semantic change if I create an Observable for each message in the actor? I'm not getting sense of it somehow!

Comment: The author is not creating an observable for each message.  The actor is the observable, acting as a publisher so it can be have subscribers hooked into it that will in turn observe the messages that are flowing through the actor.

Comment: What is the benefit of that? What is the difference between Observing and Receiving messages in the receive method?